# Convert string of Mash into Hash in Hashie gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an file generated from ruby script which uses hashie gem to convert hash in to mash as below

```
config.ip_details.ip_one.pub.heartbeat.ip1  |"198.18.0.2"|
config.vpc.vms.vse_pub.heartbeat.netmask    |"255.255.255.252"|
```

And I want to read the file and need convert the string of Mash into Hash, is their any method available in hashie gem to convert string of mash in to hash?

Comment: Did my answer help you or not? As a responsible SO user, you should accept an answer if it helped, else leave a note that it does not work with addl. details.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`to_hash` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/Hashie/Hash#to_hash-instance_method) which you can call on Mash object to get a hash back.

```
require "hashie"

hash = {:b => 23, :d => {:e => "abc"}} 
mash = Hashie::Mash.new(hash) 
p mash
#=> #<Hashie::Mash b=23 d=#<Hashie::Mash e="abc">>
p mash.to_hash
#=> {"b"=>23, "d"=>{"e"=>"abc"}}
```

To create a `Mash` object from a file (YAML), you can use [`Mash#load` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/Hashie/Mash#load-class_method):

```
mash = Hashie::Mash.load("sample.yml")
```